# Access: After Change Event

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create an access form that performs simple math. The user inputs before and after values, and as the user is inputting after value, the disabled net textbox automatically calculates and display the net value.

before: ___

after: ____

net: (=before-after)

The code I have is:

```
   Private Sub after_Change()
       net.Value = before.Value - after.Value
   End Sub
```

Two problems right now is that it changes based on the last entered value (change 5->6 it will run the code with 5). And is only runs the code on the first change, instead on every change. To run it again, you have to unselect the textbox and select it again.

What am i missing here?

Comment: An edit is not committed until the control loses focus. The calculation will not update until then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   Private Sub after_Change()
       net.Value = before.Value - after.Text
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Private Sub Form_Current
  net.Value = before.Text - after.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Nope, the .Text property is only available for the control that currently has focus, so you can never use it for two controls in one line

Answer (score 0):

In VB6: you use the controls after update event

In .net/vb.net: you use the controls after update event

In asp.net: you use the controls after update event.

With c# and winforms? - you use the controls after update event.

In FoxPro, you use the after update event.

Want to take a wild guess the event in Access to use?

hint:
After update.

So, for the two controls, you have in after update event, you have this:

```
Call MyCalc
```

And, then you have:

```
Sub MyCalc

    Me.net = me.Before – me.After

End sub
```

And if either of the controls can/will be blank or “empty”, then I suggest:

```
  Me.Net = nz(me.Before,0) – nz(me.After,0)
```

On change is really only useful for key by key processing, since as you type each character into the text box, the event fires – you really never know when the user is finished. In every development platform I can think of for the desktop of the last 25 years, the standard event is after update.

You also note that this issues 100% eliminates the need for ".text". You can thus just use the control names as per above examples.